# Filling in a new column based on a condition in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add a new column in my data frame so that for each row if `LOC == 1` then `V` is equal to the value given for `V1`; if `LOC==2` then `V` is equal to the value given for `V2`. Here is an example:

```
df <- 
LOC   V1   V2
 1    0.5  0.7
 1    0.5  0.7
 2    0.5  0.7
 1    0.6  0.8
```

Result should be:

```
df <-
 LOC   V1   V2   V
 1    0.5  0.7   0.5
 1    0.5  0.7   0.5
 2    0.5  0.7   0.7
 1    0.6  0.8   0.6
```

I need help on how to do that in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `LOC` only contains 1 or 2 then this will work

```
 df$V <- ifelse(df$LOC == 1, df$V1, df$V2)
```

Comment: It's a good solution for 2 groups, but will quickly become complex if you have >2 columns.

Comment: @thelatemail, agreed. I like your approach, sub-setting with matrices is always fun!

Answer (score 4):

Use matrix indexing:

```
idx <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)), dat$LOC)
#      row  col
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    1
#[3,]    3    2
#[4,]    4    1

dat[-1][idx]
#[1] 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.6
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there an easier way where I can added it to the data frame that I have?

Comment: @daragh - `dat$V <- dat[-1][idx]` and you're done. I'm not sure what is difficult about that.